# i need to search in google and get the count of a particular word using scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I need to search in google and get the count of a particular word using scrapy. If a  word  is given your application. I've searched in google and printed the count of the matched words. Don’t hardcode the word in the application  it should take from the console

This the code for getting count from google:

```
import scrapy
    import re

    class GoogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

        name = 'Google'
        allowed_domains = ['www.google.co.in']

        def __init__(self, word=None):
            super().__init__()
            self.word = word
            self.start_urls = ['https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+self.word]

        def parse(self, response):
            print('url:', response.url)
            text = response.xpath('//div[@class="g"]//text()').extract()        
            text = ''.join(text).lower()
            count = len(re.findall(self.word, text))
            print('count:', count)

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import sys

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
})
#c.crawl(GoogleSpider, word='abba')
c.crawl(GoogleSpider, word=sys.argv[1])
c.start()
```

While running the code by using .i am the below error. please find the solution??

```
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.google.co.in/searchq=newyear> (referer: None)
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <404 https://www.google.co.in/searchq=newyear>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 207,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1860,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 5, 58, 4, 873996),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/404': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 5, 58, 4, 500024)}
2018-01-02 11:28:04 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: again the same question - you already get asnwer. If you expected sometehing different then maybe you ask wrong question. Maybe question is unclear and you have to write it with more details.

Comment: @furas i  need to scrap after entering the data in google

Comment: "finding word" is not problem of scrapy. Scarpy gives you all text in `string` and now you have to use standard string function or regex to count word. If you don't get expected count then you have to check if Google gives you expected data - so you have to display `string` or `response.body`. It may sends data in different tags or classes than you expect - Google does it if client doesn't use JavaScript (and `scrapy` doesn't run JavaScript)` So can you find manually expected words in `response.body` ? Can you find manually `class="sbqs_c`  in `response.body` ?

Comment: to create good question you should add some word as example, and what result (number) you get for this word, and what number it should returns.

Comment: BTW: use `print()` to display `'https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0'+self.word'` and use this url in browser - it doesn't open page with results. Next use google to find word and see url used by browser. You will see difference.

Comment: @furas how to open the google and a search a word by using scrapy

Comment: stop asking how. Start thinking and checking your data. You expect we resolve all your problems and you will be only sitting. Your code gives me error - you should add this error in question. If you need answer then you have to create good question - do not expect us to do everything for you

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest mistake: you do nothing to check if you really get expected data and if there are expected word. Code also gets error message but you don't add it.

---

First mistake is url. Url `https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0'+self.word` doesn't open page with results For me works only `https://www.google.co.in/search?g='+self.word`. See `q=` instead of `dcr=0`.

Second mistake is `self.word` in `start_urls = [...]`. `start_urls` is created before `__init__` is executed so `self.word` doesn't exist yet. Inside `__init__` you have to do

```
self.start_urls = ['https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+self.word]
```

You should get error message but you didn't get this error in question - and it is big mistake.

Third mistake - this one you may not know - Google uses JavaScript on page but when you use browser or program/script which doesn't use JavaScript then it sends result in different tags and with different classes. 
Turn off JavaScript in browser and open Google again to see differences.

So there is no `class="sbqs_c"` but results are in `class="g"`

This code gives me `"count: 42"` for word `"abba"`

**EDIT:** I add `sys.argv` so now it can be run as

```
python script.py abba

python script.py "new year"
```

Code:

```
import scrapy
import re

class GoogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'Google'
    allowed_domains = ['www.google.co.in']

    def __init__(self, word=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.word = word
        self.start_urls = ['https://www.google.co.in/search?q='+self.word]

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        text = response.xpath('//*[@class="g"]//text()').extract() # text only in search results
        #text = response.xpath('//text()').extract() # all text on page

        text = ''.join(text).lower()
        count = len(re.findall(self.word, text))

        print('count:', count)

# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import sys

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
})
#c.crawl(GoogleSpider, word='abba')
c.crawl(GoogleSpider, word=sys.argv[1])
c.start()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162339/discussion-on-answer-by-furas-i-need-to-search-in-google-and-get-the-count-of-a).